# RStudio produces a TeX file with no errors, just warnings, but fails when it comes to showing the PDF

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pdflatex

I am writing a book with [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr) (not R-Markdown, nor Bookdown).

It is a multi-chapter book (like nearly all books), with child documents for each chapter. This all works fine. However when I work on my Windows machine, [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr) processes the file fine, produces the [latex](/questions/tagged/latex), and then [pdftex](/questions/tagged/pdftex) does its thing - with no errors, just warnings and badboxes, i.e. the usual LaTeX stuff, but finishes with this:

```
output file: chapter03.tex

[1] "chapter03.tex"
Running pdflatex.exe on chapter03.tex...failed

Issues: 23 warnings, 25 badboxes
```

This is true of every chapter I have worked on so far. It works fine on my Mac. It compiles fine and displays using MikTeX and TeXStudio with Windows -- again with no errors. Is there some evil Adobe thing that is stopping the PDF viewer from launching?

**Update:** I went back to my document and used `knit2pdf`. This compiled the document to a PDF without errors, and then clicking on the "Sync PDF view" button brought the compiled PDF up no issues. So, at least to me, this seems like it is still an R Studio issue - something to do with how the "Compile PDF" button is working.

I will try and create a minimal reprex.

Operating system is `Windows 10` (up to date), with the latest version of [r](/questions/tagged/r) `3.6.3`, `R-Studio`, and [miktex](/questions/tagged/miktex) `2.9` (also completely up-to-date).

Comment: Does this behave any differently when not within RStudio? (I suspect it does not, so the [tag:rstudio] tag might be inappropriate.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the point. I went back to my document and used `knit2pdf`. This compiled the document to a pdf without errors, and then clicking on the "Sync PDF view" button brought the compiled PDF up no issues. So, at least to me, this seems like it is still an R Studio issue - something to do with how the "Compile PDF" button is working.

Comment: That's fair and good information. I think that should go in the original question, as it is quite relevant. Can you reproduce the problem with a much smaller (trivial) r-markdown document? It is likely going to be difficult to troubleshoot since we don't have your data or your Rmd file.